# C#- static variables from class to class

Tags: c#

First of all, take a look at my below code:

```
    class A
    {

        public static int Flag()
        {
                    return 0;// set initial value=0 
        }

        B b= new B();
        public void afunc()
        {
           b.bfunc();
        }
    }
```

And class B recieves and sends static variable:

```
       class B
       {
            A a= new A();
            int flag= a.Flag();
            public void bfunc()
            {
                if(flag==0) 
                 { 
                    flag=1;//???? is this wrong???
                    //do some thing
                 }
             }

        }
```

Class A send to B a static variable with initial value=0; then class A call bfunc from class B. In bfunc() I set flag=1. I'm a new  to C#. Can you share me how class A recieves back flag=1 sended by class B. I mean which syntax?

Comment: do you really want a static method? it looks like a property of `A` to me

Comment: What do you want to achieve by this? I'm kinda confused... Why do you need to get 0 from the A class if it will always give you 0 as static method?

Comment: I feel like a nobody... :( I mean, I feel like Ms. Nobody, as I too am a bit confused about the question. What is the goal here?

Comment: @Sayse I just want a static variable, but it I use: public static int Flag=0 like a variable-> I dont know how to get it at class B. I've used: new B().Flag=1 --> but it's wrong syntax

Answer (score 2):

a few things are wrong here

1. `Flag` is a method on A, so you cannot change its "value"
2. `Flag` is static therefore it does not have an instance which is what I think you want
3. I suspect you want Flag to be a property of A

   ```
   public int Flag{get;set;}
   ```
4. You are making new instances of `A` and `B`, which may be correct for you but be weary this means you are not referencing existing instances
5. You have two options

A

```
 this.Flag = b.bFunc();

 public int bFunc()
   .... return 1;
```

B

```
 public void bFunc()
 ... a.Flag = 1;
```

If you really want static variable then

```
public static int Flag = 0;
A.Flag = x
```

Answer (score 0):

Were is no static variable here, you only have a static function `int Flag()`. To get value of a `flag` in class A, you must return this value from function `bfunc()` like this:

```
public int bfunc()
        {
            if(flag==0) 
             { 
                flag=1;
                return flag;
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you properly because there are many things wrong with your code. `Flag` should be a property instead of a method so you can store your value. The way you used it was just tossing out a zero.

First, your two classes. Keep in mind that usually properties should be used as accesssors to private fields, but let's do it the simplest way.

```
class A
{
    public static int Flag = 0;
}

class B
{
    public void bfunc()
    {
        if (A.Flag == 0)
        {
            A.Flag = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use them as follows to change `Flag`'s value.

```
B bObject = new B();
bObject.bfunc();
// A.Flag is now 1.
```

Note that `bfunc()` will change `Flag`'s value to 1 only if it was 0 before.

Comment: I don't think you can change property value of class constructor, but you need to make a new member of that class first and apply that on it?

Comment: @Ms.Nobody No S_F is correct, That's not a class constructor that's a static field within the class that is initialized to `0` when the Type `A` is first referenced.

Comment: @BobVale not sure if I understand well, but I thought that if there is something static, you can't change it, but now you are changing the static int value. Mhmmm...?

Comment: I don't use statics ever so I'm not sure if the name means how it really is.. so just asking.

Comment: @Ms.Nobody static means you don't need an instance, its declared on the type.  so given `public class A { public static int X; public int Y }` you would reference `A.X` but `Y` would need an instance e.g. `new A().Y`

Comment: @BobVale hmm, thx.. interesting, I would never think it is supposed to work like that from the word static X_X.. weird :D